# Write bootable partition on USB flash disk

Tags: partitioning, disk, boot-partition

How can I easily copy partition of my disk into the USB flash drive? (Ubuntu 14.04)

Comment: Write or copy or transfer?

Comment: Copy from the disk to the USB